# unexpected results - can please some one point the mistake

Tags: java, arrays

after spending number of hours and trying different things, i can't figure out what is wrong with my code, it's a simple program : `

```
public class AssignGrades {

private int ntotal=0;
private int []y;

//constructor to initialize class instances
AssignGrades(int t)
{
    ntotal = t;
    //y = num1;

}   
AssignGrades( int []num1)
{
    y=num1;
    for (int i=0;i<y.length;i++)
    y[i] = num1[i];

}   
//method to sort grades int []num1

void setGrades()
{
    int [] y = new int[ntotal];
    for (int i=0;i<y.length;i++)

    {

        //assign grades 
        if 
            (y[i]<80){
        System.out.println("grade is A" +y[i]);}
            else if (y[i]<70)
            System.out.println("grade is B" +y[i]);
           else if (y[i]<60)
            System.out.println("grade is c" +y[i]);
           else
             System.out.println("FAIL" +y[i]);
      } 
          }

//show student grades - to print array[] values 
void  showGrades()
{
    for (int u: y)
    System.out.println(u);
}
```

}`

my client program

```
`import java.util.Scanner;


 public class AssignGradesDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int t=0;

    System.out.println("enter no of students" );

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    {
        t=input.nextInt();          
    //  input.close();
    }


    int [] num1 = new int[t];
    System.out.println("enter grades");

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0;i<num1.length;i++)
    {
        num1[i]=input1.nextInt();           
    }
    input1.close();

    AssignGrades ag = new AssignGrades(t);
    AssignGrades ag1 = new AssignGrades( num1);

    ag.setGrades();
    ag1.showGrades();

}


}
```

output is:

```
enter no of students
2
enter grades
78
98
grade is A0
grade is A0
78
98
```

Question: now in the output 'A' and '0' -> where the problem is, it looks like array is not initialized, all the values appear to be zero: whereas when I print them separately, they are initialized.?!

Please let me know if more clarification is required. thanks

Comment: You have local var y and class var y with same name. That looks suspicious.

Comment: @peter.petrov Go ahead and post an answer; that looks to be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a local variable called y and a class variable with the same name y. That seems to be the problem. You are using the local y but you meant to use the class y, I think.

OK, your code had lots of problems. Here is the fixed version.

```
public class AssignGrades {

    private int[] y;

    public AssignGrades(int[] num1) {
        y = num1;
    }

    // method to set grades
    void setGrades() {
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
        {
            // assign grades

            if (y[i] < 50)
                System.out.println("FAIL" + y[i]);
            else if (y[i] < 60)
                System.out.println("grade is C" + y[i]);
            else if (y[i] < 70)
                System.out.println("grade is B" + y[i]);
            else if (y[i] < 80) {
                System.out.println("grade is A" + y[i]);
            }

        }
    }

    // method to show student grades
    void showGrades() {
        for (int u : y){
            System.out.println(u);
        }
    }

}




import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignGradesDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int t = 0;
        System.out.println("enter no of students");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = input.nextInt();

        int[] num1 = new int[t];
        System.out.println("enter grades");

        for (int i = 0; i < num1.length; i++) {
            num1[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        input.close();

        AssignGrades ag = new AssignGrades(num1);

        ag.setGrades();
        ag.showGrades();
    }

}
```

Comment: that seems to be normal practice. I initialized class instance variables via constructor `AssignGrades( int []num1)` and then used methods to manipulate data in those variables ..

Comment: @kasper_341 Don't know which practice you talk about but in setGrades all the elements of your array are 0s because you do not initialize them. The local y covers the class y, you don't use the class y there.

Comment: yes all elements of array y[] are 0s - i initialized array `int [] y = new int[ntotal];
    for (int i=0;i<y.length;i++)`in method `void setGrades()` 
and later I used the same variable in method `void  showGrades()`
`{
    for (int u: y)
    System.out.println(u);
}` and prints all array elements.

Comment: @kasper_341 1) you cannot use local variables from one method in another; 2) int [] y = new int[ntotal] this is not really initialization, this creates an array with elements which are 0s only; in the other method they are not visible 3) in showGrades you use the class variable y

Comment: @kasper_341 I just fixed your code. There were many issues with it. Compare it with your version. Put the two classes in two separate files. Run the demo class.

Comment: ok yes it does fix the problem - outpit is :
`enter no of students
2
enter grades
89
67
grade is A89
grade is c67
89
67`

Comment: i am a beginner and still learning just so that am clear - I initialized the array via constructor `void setGrades()
for (int i=0;i<y.length;i++)` and created and declared using this statement `int [] y = new int[ntotal];`
2) so how does this statement `int [] y = new int[ntotal];` and specifying access modifier `public ` solves the problem - it will be of great help.

Comment: 3) if I cannot use local variables from one method to another than how does it print array element in method `void  showGrades()`
it will be of great help and thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: @kasper_341 Sure. NP. To reuse data from one method in another one needs to use class variables. In the fixed version of the code, we reuse the y class variable in the two methods. This variable belongs to the ag object created here "AssignGrades ag = new AssignGrades(num1);" So this variable is not lost until the ag object is there. All the methods of ag have access to that shared y class variable.